# javascript_include_tag and stylesheet_link_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, include, stylesheet, assets

1. I would like to know  if there is some standard (Rails-version-independent) folder in Rails application where to put javascripts or stylesheets.
2. when I insert javascript_include_tag and stylesheet_link_tag they link to /assets by default. How to specify folder, containing javascripts or folder containing stylesheets?
3. I read that there is some Rails.application.config.assets.paths configuration thing which lets me to specify folder for assets (btw. in which .rb file should I assign its value?). But it seems to point out a single folder for all JS and CSS files together, but I want to store them in separate folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For rails 3 you can put all your javascripts and CSS files in public/assets/javascripts and public/assets/stylesheets
   javascript_include_tag will be linked correctly in that case.
   For rails 2 the same, just leave assets out.
2. those tags are helpers, so they point to the asset folder and respectively the folder /javascripts or /stylesheets.

   ```
   <%= javascript_include_tag "something" %>
   ```

   generates a link to /assets/javascripts/something.js
3. You can edit the path in config/application.rb just place

   ```
   config.assets.enabled = true
   config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/or_whatever_path_to_use"
   ```

   in there

Comment: 2. as for me, I get just /assets/something.js, and that is my biggest problem.

Comment: customize the root of assets path by defining Base.asset_host
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html ;

`ActionController::Base.asset_host = "assets.example.com"`

in environments/development.rb, environments/production.rb

Comment: sorry I misread your comment, /assets/something.js is correct, on the server it will point to the javascript folder.
The app/assets/stylesheets and app/assets/javascripts folder is just the physical location of the scripts and sheets, on the server they end up in one big pile @ yourserver.com/assets/